# Does indexing in Postgres improve ordering speed?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

Let's say you have a table with a primary key `A`, and two columns `B` and `C`.

When querying we want to do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE A = 'thing' ORDER BY B, C`

Since `A` is a primary key, it already has an index. Is there any benefit to adding an index on `B` and `C` in terms of speeding up ordering?

Comment: there is if the result is more than a few records. The thing is that a primary key is unique and you should get only 1 record for this query. So there is no sense in ordering one record.

Comment: Check the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html)

Comment: @juergend Good point. What if the primary key is all `(A, B, C)`?

Comment: you can even check a pretty execution plan using : http://tatiyants.com/pev/#/plans/new

Comment: @BigMoney: Then there is automatically an index on those columns.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. You're retrieving 1 row, there is no order involved. You can't sort 1 element. The element comes first, and last, but never after itself. As I said, I don't understand your question.

Comment: How do you want to order a single record? You’re searching on the primary key, thus a single record. There is nothing to order, you can leave that part from the query out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query cannot benefit from additional indexes.

If `a` is the primary key, then the query can only return zero or one rows, so ordering is trivial and cannot be made faster.

In fact, you should omit the `ORDER BY` clause.